# My mac mini freezes - only mouse cursor is alive. What is a problem?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, performance

I do not like to shutdown my Mac mini - so it works 24/7.
But sometimes it freezes - I can move my mouse cursor, but anything else is frozen - screen does not react to clicks/keyboard presses - it's like it's not a GUI anymore, but screenshot of it.

It seems that this problem happens when MEMORY PRESSURE indicator from Activity Monitor is "high" http://prntscr.com/eqcaan

Here's the output of **/var/log/system.log** before freeze:

```
Mar 30 16:05:21 yaru kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0, region 0x7fff92400000->0x7fff92600000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Mar 30 16:05:21 yaru kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8021c4e780) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8021c4e780, region 0x7fff92400000->0x7fff92600000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Mar 30 16:05:21 yaru kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0, region 0x7fff92400000->0x7fff92600000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Mar 30 16:13:28 yaru WindowServer[111]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [262583988230703]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
Mar 30 16:13:28 yaru WindowServer[111]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
Mar 30 16:13:30 yaru com.apple.IconServicesAgent[46588]: IconServicesAgent launched.
Mar 30 16:13:46 yaru kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff801a525780) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff801a525780, region 0x7fff92400000->0x7fff92600000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Mar 30 16:13:52 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46479 [secd]
Mar 30 16:13:52 yaru WiFiKeychainProxy[46478]: xpc __securityd_create_connection_block_invoke got event: Connection interrupted
Mar 30 16:13:52 yaru EscrowSecurityAlert[1303]: xpc __securityd_create_connection_block_invoke got event: Connection interrupted
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46478 [WiFiKeychainProx]
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.wifi.WiFiKeychainProxy[46478]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.wifi.WiFiKeychainProxy[46478]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.secd[46479]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.secd[46479]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46490 [systemstatsd]
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemstatsd[46490]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemstatsd[46490]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru WiFiKeychainProxy[46600]: [NO client logger] <Nov 10 2013 18:30:13> WIFICLOUDSYNC WiFiCloudSyncEngineCreate: created...
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru WiFiKeychainProxy[46600]: [NO client logger] <Nov 10 2013 18:30:13> WIFICLOUDSYNC WiFiCloudSyncEngineRegisterCallbacks: WiFiCloudSyncEngineCallbacks version - 0, bundle id - com.apple.wifi.WiFiKeychainProxy
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46588 [com.apple.IconSe]
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.IconServicesAgent[46588]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru NotificationCenter[228]: XPC error messaging com.apple.IconServicesAgent: Connection interrupted
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru NotificationCenter[228]: XPC error messaging com.apple.IconServicesAgent: Connection invalid
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46589 [xpcd]
Mar 30 16:13:53 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpcd.F5010000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[46589]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46587 [tccd]
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.tccd[46587]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.tccd[46587]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46483 [cfprefsd]
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[46483]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:54 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[46483]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:55 yaru kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff801fb3d4b0, region 0x7fff92400000->0x7fff92600000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Mar 30 16:13:57 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46486 [cfprefsd]
Mar 30 16:13:57 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent[46486]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:13:57 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent[46486]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:13:58 yaru secd[46601]:  __EnsureFreshParameters_block_invoke_2 SOSCloudKeychainSynchronizeAndWait: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SyncedDefaults error 1025 - Remote error : No valid account for KVS)
Mar 30 16:13:58 yaru secd[46601]:  __talkWithKVS_block_invoke callback error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SyncedDefaults error 1025 - Remote error : No valid account for KVS)
Mar 30 16:13:58 yaru secd[46601]:  CFPropertyListReadFromFile file file:///Users/yaru/Library/Keychains/86807F43-9F9E-5B7B-A602-92BCD9CB8003/accountStatus.plist: The file “accountStatus.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
Mar 30 16:14:01 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46597 [com.apple.InputM]
Mar 30 16:14:02 yaru kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 46598 [librariand]
Mar 30 16:14:02 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.librariand[46598]): Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Mar 30 16:14:02 yaru com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170] (com.apple.librariand[46598]): assertion failed: 13F1911: launchd + 43321 [364E35A7-9FA7-3950-8494-40B49A2E7250]: 0x9
Mar 30 16:14:02 yaru com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.InputMethodKit.UserDictionary[46597]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 30 16:14:03 yaru secd[46601]:  SecErrorGetOSStatus unknown error domain: com.apple.security.sos.error for error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Public Key not available - failed to register before call)
Mar 30 16:14:03 yaru secd[46601]:  securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler WiFiKeychainProx[46600] DeviceInCircle The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Public Key not available - failed to register before call)
Mar 30 16:14:21 yaru WindowServer[111]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Google Chrome" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
Mar 30 16:14:22 yaru WindowServer[111]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Google Chrome" after 2.82 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.69 seconds)
Mar 30 16:14:27 yaru WindowServer[111]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "loginwindow" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
Mar 30 16:15:46 yaru kernel[0]: IOHIDSystem: postEvent LLEventQueue overflow.
Mar 30 16:15:46 yaru WindowServer[111]: disable_update_likely_unbalanced: UI updates still disabled by application "loginwindow" after 79.92 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.12 seconds). Likely an unbalanced disableUpdate call.
Mar 30 16:31:13 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1490880673 0
```

Comment: Does it freeze in any particular application? I have found that my iMac often does this, but it always seems to be in Safari.

Comment: I do not use Safari. But Chrome is always opened. I use Chrome for development - so I need it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - it was my HDD and SSD - they were failing. After I replaced them to new ones - problem is gone. DriveDX software helped me to figure it out.